# Create a wave animation like the one on the Android 4.0 lock screen

Tags: android, android-animation

How can one create a wave like animation, like the one which appears when one touches the screen on an Android 4.0 lock screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar in one of my app. The way I did is putting the whole wave as one big image then you repeatedly change it's source in background to give it animated look & feel.

Basically, when onTouchUp you start the animation and have it loop and update the image sources until finish. Then you switch its source to the original image in onAnimationFinish.

That's just from the top of my head so I'm not sure if it's accurate or not. I reckon you get the idea anyway. If there's easier way to pull it off then I'm willing to listen as well.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/RomainPiel/Titanic) is the solution you want to implement let me know if it doesn't work.

**Code sample :-**

```
Add a TitanicTextView to your layout:

<com.romainpiel.titanic.TitanicTextView
    android:id="@+id/titanic_tv"
    android:text="@string/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#212121"
    android:textSize="70sp"/>
```

**To start the animation:**

```
titanic = new Titanic();
titanic.start(myTitanicTextView);
```

You may want to keep track of the titanic instance after the animation is started if you want to stop it.

**To stop it:**

```
titanic.cancel();
```